# Parsing an Int from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In javascript, what is the best way to parse an INT from a string which starts with a letter (such as "test[123]")?  I need something that will work for the example below.

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(':input').change( function() {
        id = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));  //fails for the data below
        alert(id);
    });
}
```

My generated HTML:

```
<select id="attribute[123]">
<!-- various options -->
</select>
<select id="attribute[456]">
<!-- various options -->
</select>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to match the number:

```
$(this).attr("id").match(/\d+/)
```

Comment: Checkmark for succinctness and readability.  Thanks to all though. : )

Comment: Note that the regex should be changed to "/[-+]?\d+/" for a more general case (to allow signed ints), but that looks unnecessary for the OP's situation.

Comment: What would make it more robust is to do $(this).attr("id").match(/\\[(\d+)\\]/)[1] since that would allow things like "attribute7[123]"

Comment: an explanation here would be very helpful.

Answer (score 25):

```
parseInt(input.replace(/[^0-9-]/,""),10)
```

Comment: Interestingly, this will NOT work if given valid float literals like "1e10"

Comment: Of course it won't work for floats.  The op specifically asked about ints.

Answer (score 1):

Probably just filter out the string with .replace(). If there is another way then I am unaware of it:

```
parseInt("attribute[123]".replace("attribute[", "").replace("]", "")));
```

You could probably use some Regex to put that in only one .replace(), but I'm not good with Regex so I just did it twice.

Test this in your browser with

```
javascript:alert(parseInt("attribute[123]".replace("attribute[", "").replace("]", "")));
```

Should alert 123.