# How to parse a number from a text input or assign 0 if it is null?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with this, even though it seems fairly simple. I have the following jquery snippet that assigns a numeric value from the text input with the id salary to the javascript variable.

If this text field is empty, I would like to assign 0 to the javascript variable, salary.

```
salary = parseFloat($("#salary").val());
```

Is there a simple, concise way to do this in javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448666/parsing-an-int-from-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) will return `NaN` if it is unable to parse the input, and becaue `NaN` is falsy, you can simply use the [`||` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

```
salary = parseFloat($("#salary").val()) || 0;
```

If it is unable to parse the input to a valid number (or it is parsed as `0`), this will return `0`.

Comment: Right you are. My mistake. Thank you for this quick and easy solution. Makes sense after seeing it, I did not know you could use the or operator like that.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var salary = parseFloat($("#salary").val()) || 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var value = $("#salary").val();
salary = parseFloat(value != '' ? value : 0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var a = $("#salary").val();
 salary = parseFloat((a!="")?a:0);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use Number function

```
salary = Number($("#salary").val()) == "NaN" ? 0 : Number($("#salary").val());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(!$.trim($("#salary").val()).length == 0 ) { // zero-length string AFTER a trim
            salary = parseFloat($("#salary").val());
     }
else{
salary =0;
}
```