# sum of two changing variables not totally correctly using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is easier to see my codepen link: https://codepen.io/ScottFSchmidt/pen/GPWvQP  Everything works, but the total of the total of the two variables are not adding up.

**Failed attempts**. There were 4 major failed attempts that I had (I tried other stuff too). I am wondering if I need to use eval.

```
$total.text(pizzaPrice.innerHTML+sodaPrice.innerHTML);  //returns NAN
$total.text( $sodaTotal + $pizzaTotal);  //returns 6 at ALL times, adding one pizza and one soda. 
$total.text( $sodaTotal.val + $pizzaTotal.val ); //function (e){var t,n,r,i=this[0];{if(arguments.length)return r=g(e),this.each(function(n){var i;1===this.nodeType&
 function sum($pizzaTotal, $sodaTotal) {
    $sodaTotal+$pizzaTotal.html($total);
} //won't trigger with sum() but probably not the easiest way.
```

`
**Full Code:** 
commented stuff out is stuff that did not work:

```
<script text=type/javascript>
  $(document).ready(function(){
var $pizzaOptions = $( '.pizza-options' );
var pizzaPrice    = $pizzaOptions.data( 'price' );
var $sodaOptions  = $( '.soda-options' );
var sodaPrice     = $sodaOptions.data( 'price' );
var $pizzaTotal   = $( '.pizza-total' );
var $sodaTotal    = $( '.soda-total' );
var $total         = $( '.total' );

    $total.text(pizzaPrice+sodaPrice);
   // $total.text( $sodaTotal.val + $pizzaTotal.val );

      function sum($pizzaTotal, $sodaTotal) {
        $sodaTotal+$pizzaTotal.html($total);
    }

  function calculator( $totalEl, price, $options ) {
  return function ( e ) {
    $totalEl.text( price * $options.find( '[type="checkbox"]:checked' ).length );
  };
    //$sum=$sum+$totalEl;
    //$total.text($sum)
    //sum();
 }


  $pizzaOptions.on( 'click', calculator( $pizzaTotal, pizzaPrice, $pizzaOptions ) );
     //$pizzaOptions.on( 'click', sum($pizzaTotal, $sodaTotal);
    //// $pizzaOptions.on( 'click', sum();
      $sodaOptions.on( 'click', calculator( $sodaTotal, sodaPrice, $sodaOptions ) );
  }); //end ready
</script>
```

Almost every suggested article is using SQL not Jquery. Most of the failed attempt ideas were from suggested articles. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Everything you get from HTML is string, convert the strings to numbers before doing maths.

Comment: Yeah I figured something like that was the case....  `$total.text(pizzaPrice.innerHTML+sodaPrice.innerHTML);`  returned NAN. I will try to find other methods....

Comment: First attempt `innerHTML` will return a string, you need to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sum` function was never called, and it isn't completely correct.

Change sum to:

```
function sum() {
    $total.text(Number($pizzaTotal.text())+Number($sodaTotal.text()));
}
```

Here we set the text of $total to $pizzaTotal + $sodaTotal. It would be a lot better to use variable instead of doing it this way.

Change calculator to:

```
function calculator( $totalEl, price, $options ) {
    $totalEl.text( price * $options.find( '[type="checkbox"]:checked' ).length );
}
```

Now the function will set the text instead of just returning another function.

Lastly change your click listeners to use an anonymous function, calling both calculator and sum:

```
$pizzaOptions.on( 'click', function() {
  calculator( $pizzaTotal, pizzaPrice, $pizzaOptions );
  sum();
});

$sodaOptions.on( 'click', function() {
  calculator( $sodaTotal, sodaPrice, $sodaOptions );
  sum();
});
```

Now they will also call sum when they're executed.

Here it is all together https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZVexyP

Comment: Your method seems much easier to understand than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448666/parsing-an-int-from-a-string-in-javascript. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[codepen.io/ScottFSchmidt/pen/GPWvQP?editors=1010](http://codepen.io/ScottFSchmidt/pen/GPWvQP?editors=1010)
**Here is the full length solution:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="order-form">

  <div class="pizza-options" data-price="5">
    <h2>Pizza</h2>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="sausage"> Sausage
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="pepperoni" data-price=".5"> Pepperoni
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="mushrooms"> Mushrooms
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="soda-options" data-price="2">
    <h2>Soda</h2>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="coke"> Coke
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="pepsi"> Pepsi
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="totals">
    <p>
      <strong>Pizza Total:</strong> <span class="pizza-total"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Soda Total:</strong> <span class="soda-total"></span>
    </p>
      <p>
      <strong>Sub Total:</strong> <span class="subtotal"></span>
    </p>
  </div>

</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var $pizzaOptions = $( '.pizza-options' );
var pizzaPrice    = +$pizzaOptions.data( 'price' );
var $sodaOptions  = $( '.soda-options' );
var sodaPrice     = +$sodaOptions.data( 'price' );
var $pizzaTotal   = $( '.pizza-total' );
var $sodaTotal    = $( '.soda-total' );
var $total = $( '.subtotal' );

function calculator( $totalEl, price, $options ) {
    $totalEl.text( price * $options.find( '[type="checkbox"]:checked' ).length);
}

function sum() {
    $total.text(Number($pizzaTotal.text())+Number($sodaTotal.text()));
}

$pizzaOptions.on( 'click', function() {
  calculator( $pizzaTotal, pizzaPrice, $pizzaOptions );
  sum();
});

$sodaOptions.on( 'click', function() {
  calculator( $sodaTotal, sodaPrice, $sodaOptions );
  sum();
});
```